# how to prove a uniformly convex Banach space is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove a uniformly convex Banach space is reflexive.  This is an amazing result, it will be easier to prove that a Banach space is reflexive.
I only know that there is not much relation between strict convex and  uniformly convex.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

This is [Milman-Pettis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milman-Pettis_theorem), see e.g. [here](http://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/uniform-convexity-and-reflexivity.pdf), page 3, or Theorem 2 on page 37 of

*Diestel, Joseph*, [**Geometry of Banach spaces. Selected topics**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0082079), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 485. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. XI, 282 p. (1975). [ZBL0307.46009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0307.46009).

The book also gives an alternative proof on pp. 44-48.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: See the edit.